# How can I move email messages from Exchange Online to Gmail?

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

We have an Exchange Online mailbox that received hundreds of emails that were supposed to be forwarded via an inbox rule to an @gmail.com address.  I've setup an inbox rule to handle any new messages but I need to "easily" get the old messages into the Gmail mailbox.

If I export the old messages to a PST the user has the hassle of trying to import this into Gmail using an Outlook client.  Is there a way to "redirect" not forward all the old messages to the @gmail.com address?  The goal being the preserve the original email headers when the message is forwarded to the @gmail.com.  I don't want the message to appear as forwarded.

I've not been able to find a way to do this after a message has been received.  I've been looking at ways with PowerShell, EWS, etc.  Any solution is acceptable.

Comment: "Any solution is acceptable." seems to contradict, "If I export the old messages to a PST the user has the hassle of trying to import this into Gmail using an Outlook client." You already wrote a very good solution into the question and even wrote that you'll accept any solution... but I guess not the solution you already know about? As far as I know, that's the only solution. You can alway have the user authenticate a separate Outlook client to their gmail and then you can do the import instead of them.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail has the ability to pull messages from an external account over POP3.

In Gmail:

1. Click the **Gear** icon
2. Go to **Settings**
3. Click **Accounts and Import**
4. Click **Add a POP3 mail account you own**
5. Use the following server information

   POP Server: outlook.office365.com

   Port: 995

   Check the box for Always use a secure connection (SSL)